# Passing powershell command as json string into subprocess

Tags: python, json, powershell, subprocess

I have a json file that contains a list of installers in the order of their priority. The `STEP_NAME` is the name of the installers and the `REQUIREMENTS` contains the list of installers to be installed first.

`STEP` defines the name of the installer and `COMMAND` is the powershell command to be executed in order to install the installer.

```
{
 {
        "STEP_NAME" : "Second_Installer",
        "REQUIREMENT" :
        [
            {
                "KEY": "First_Installer",
                "TYPE": "STEP"
            },
            {
                "KEY":  "Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command { cd $env:userprofile\\Installers\\Second_Installer; .\\install.bat; }",
                "TYPE": "COMMAND"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "STEP_NAME" : "First_Installer",
        "REQUIREMENT" :
        [                
            {
                "KEY": "Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command { &{cd $env:userprofile\\Installers\\First_Installer; .\\install.bat; }}",
                "TYPE": "COMMAND"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have a python script that checks if the key in the json file is installed.
So it has to install `first_installer` first, only then it can install the `second_installer`.

My python code is:

```
def run_step(self, step):
    # If step was a Requirement, find the matching STEP_NAME
    for item in self.installer_json_data:
        if item['STEP_NAME'] == step:
            step = item

    for req in step['REQUIREMENT']:
        if self.STEP_DONE[step['STEP_NAME']] == False:
            if req['TYPE'] == self.STEP_TYPES[0]:
                self.run_step(req['KEY'])
            elif req['TYPE'] == self.STEP_TYPES[1]:
                commandExecutor = subprocess.Popen(req['KEY'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
                print("Installing "+ step['STEP_NAME'])
                commandExecutor.communicate()
                time.sleep(5)
                while commandExecutor.poll() is None:
                    # Decode default byte stream to utf-8 and replace all un-decodable bytes to handle ISO-8859-1
                    output = codecs.decode(commandExecutor.stdout.readline(), 'utf-8', 'replace')
                    #print(output.strip()) # strip removes trailing \n 
                if commandExecutor.returncode == 0:
                    print("Installed " + step['STEP_NAME'])
                    self.STEP_DONE[step['STEP_NAME']] = True
                else:
                    print('Failed to install ' + step['STEP_NAME'])
                    break
```

But after executing the script, it says that the installers have been installed when they are actually not.

Can someone please advice what am I doing wrong?

P.S. - These installers need to be installed as Administrator